# An NP-hard problem reduces to its complement?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard, np

I found this statement in a true/false test section:
[image]

Could someone explain in laymans why this is a true statement?

My understanding is that if $X$ is $\mathcal{NP}$-hard, then its complement must be $\operatorname{co-\mathcal{NP}}$-hard. However, here we are assuming that a language that is $\operatorname{co-\mathcal{NP}}$-hard ($\overline X$) is reduceable to an $\mathcal{NP}$-complete language (3SAT). This is where I get lost. I think this means $\mathcal{NP}$-hard = $\mathcal{NP}$, and thus $X$ will reduce to its complement in this world.

Comment: That's a mathematical statement; it might require a mathematical explanation.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $\overline X$ is $\operatorname{co\mathcal{NP}}$-hard since $X$ is $\mathcal{NP}$-hard ([try to see why](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-NP-complete)).
Since 3SAT is in $\mathcal{NP}$, any problem that can be reduced to 3SAT is in NP as well. So the statement suggests that the $\operatorname{co\mathcal{NP}}$-hard language $\overline X$ is in $\mathcal{NP}$.

On the other hand, saying that $\overline{X}$ is in $\mathcal{NP}$ is equivalent to saying that $X$ is in $\operatorname{co\mathcal{NP}}$. So in total we have $X \in \operatorname{co\mathcal{NP}}$ and $\overline X$ is $\operatorname{co\mathcal{NP}}$-hard. So we get $X \leq_m^p \overline X$ by the definition of hardness.

---

Here is a bit of intuition of the fact that, if $X$ is $\mathcal{NP}$-hard, then $\overline{X}$ is $\operatorname{co\mathcal{NP}}$-hard.

Let $A$ be an arbitrary language in $\operatorname{co\mathcal{NP}}$. We have to show that $A \leq_m^p \overline{X}$. Let $B := \overline{A}$. Then $B$ is in $\mathcal{NP}$ and hence, $B \leq_m^p X$. This means there is a function $f$ computable in polynomial time, such that for an arbitrary word $x$, $x \in B$ if and only if $f(x) \in X$.

Now we show that $A \leq_m^p \overline{X}$. For a given word $x$. Using the same reduction $f$, we have $x \in A$ if and only if $x \notin B$ if and only if $f(x) \notin \overline{X}$ if and only if $f(x) \in X$.

---

Another note. Your intuition was right, but in the sentence

> I think this means $\mathcal{NP}$-hard = $\mathcal{NP}$, and thus $X$ will reduce to its complement in this world.

You should have probably said $\mathcal{NP}$ = $\operatorname{co\mathcal{NP}}$.

Comment: By the way, you don't need explicit "edit tags" in your posts. It's only confusing to people coming to your post for the first time. Besides, if I want, I can always click to see the edit history of the post :-)

Comment: I removed the tag. I thought it would have been more confusing to people who already read it if I edited/added paragraphs without hints

Comment: I'm on my phone so it's hard to find a link, but I have a question about this on meta if you are interested.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post

Comment: @narekBojikian You mention 'coNP-hard language --X is in NP. Then you mention that --X is in coNP-hard and use this to result in the final required reduction. Certainly it can't be the case that --X is in both NP and coNP-hard, so why do you get to pick and choose to use the fact that --X is in coNP-hard whilst ignoring your statement that --X is in NP?

Comment: I am not choosing the language. The statement in the question assuming a language $X$ with two given properties exists. The properties I found were equivalent to these properties. On the other hand, It is not impossible to have NP-hard language in coNP, we only still do not know such a language and such a language would imply that NP=coNP